# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{\sqrt{2 a^{3} x-x^{4}}-a \sqrt[3]{a^{2} x}}{a-\sqrt[4]{a x^{3}}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> How to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{\sqrt{2 a^{3} x-x^{4}}-a \sqrt[3]{a^{2} x}}{a-\sqrt[4]{a x^{3}}}$?

My process:
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{\sqrt{2 a^{3} x-x^{4}}-a \sqrt[3]{a^{2} x}}{a-\sqrt[4]{a x^{3}}}=\frac{\sqrt{2 a^{3} a-a^{4}}-a \sqrt[3]{a^{2} a}}{a-\sqrt[4]{a a^{3}}}=\frac{\sqrt{a^4}-a\cdot \sqrt[3]{a^3}}{a-\sqrt[4]{a^4}}=\frac{a^2-a\cdot a}{a-a}=\frac{a^2-a^2}{a-a}
\end{align}
which would be undefined, but [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) calculated this:

> $\lim_{x\to a} \, \frac{\sqrt{2 a^3 x-x^4}-a \sqrt[3]{a^2 x}}{a-\sqrt[4]{a x^3}}=
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \frac{16 a}{9} & a\geq 0 \\
>  0 & (\text{otherwise}) \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}$

What have I done wrong? Is there a way to calculate the limit with L'Hospitals Rule?

Comment: there is a way: multiply by an expression to make numerator look like $v^6-w^6$, then multiply  by an expression to make denominator look like $t^4-u^4$

Comment: As $x\to a$, your fallacy is in thinking $f(x,\,a)\to0,\,g(x,\,a)\to0$ prevents $f/g$ having a $\to0$ limit. (An easy counterexample is $f=g=x-a$.) What it does prevent is you calculating any such limit as a ratio of the limits of $f,\,g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that by $y=x/a\to 1$

$$\frac{\sqrt{2 a^{3} x-x^{4}}-a \sqrt[3]{a^{2} x}}{a-\sqrt[4]{a x^{3}}}=a \frac{\sqrt{2 y-y^{4}}-\sqrt[3]{y}}{1-\sqrt[4]{y^3}}=$$

$$= -a \frac{y-1}{\sqrt[4]{y^3}-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{2 y-y^{4}}-1}{y-1}- \frac{\sqrt[3]{y}-1}{y-1}\right)=f(y)$$

then use the definition of derivative to obtain

$$f(y)\to -a\cdot \frac43\left(-1-\frac13\right)=\frac{16a}9$$

Comment: I should compute $f'(y)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h}$ or what do you mean by "use the definition of the derivative"?

Comment: For example for $h(y)= \sqrt[4]{y^3} $ we have $$\lim_{y\to1}\frac{\sqrt[4]{y^3}-1} {y-1}=h’(1)=\frac34$$

Comment: And so on for $g(y)=\frac{\sqrt{2 y-y^{4}}-1}{y-1}$ and $ l(y)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{y}-1}{y-1}$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you!

Comment: @Doesbaddel Well done! Let me know if something else is not clear.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @user's answer, starting with $x=a y$, we have
$$A=\frac{\sqrt{2 a^{3} x-x^{4}}-a \sqrt[3]{a^{2} x}}{a-\sqrt[4]{a x^{3}}}=a\frac{ \sqrt[3]{y}-\sqrt{y \left(2-y^3\right)}}{y^{3/4}-1}$$ Now, let $y=1+t$ to get
$$A=a\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+t}-\sqrt{1-2 t-6 t^2-4 t^3-t^4}}{(1+t)^{3/4}-1}$$ Now, using Taylor series around $t=0$ or binomial expansion
$$A=a \left(\frac{16}{9}+\frac{128 }{27}t+O\left(t^2\right) \right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.